# Tem como determinar uma linha de código para cada navegador?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

Quero que no Google Chrome meu site tenha `width: Xpx;` e no Safari tenha `width: Ypx;`, isso é possível?

Comment: Por javascript acredito que você consegue determinar qual arquivo carregar para cada browser... exemplos que você pode adaptar a sua necessidade: http://prodwebdigital.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/identificando-navegador-para-uso-de-css.html  e http://tableless.com.br/identificando-os-ies/

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso de diversas formas...

### [Javascript "puro"](http://codepen.io/isvaldo/pen/ZYxKrw)

```js
var BrowserDetect = {
        init: function () {
            this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "Other";
            this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent) || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion) || "Unknown";
        },
        searchString: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var dataString = data[i].string;
                this.versionSearchString = data[i].subString;

                if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) !== -1) {
                    return data[i].identity;
                }
            }
        },
        searchVersion: function (dataString) {
            var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
            if (index === -1) {
                return;
            }

            var rv = dataString.indexOf("rv:");
            if (this.versionSearchString === "Trident" && rv !== -1) {
                return parseFloat(dataString.substring(rv + 3));
            } else {
                return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index + this.versionSearchString.length + 1));
            }
        },

        dataBrowser: [
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Chrome", identity: "Chrome"},
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "MSIE", identity: "Explorer"},
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Trident", identity: "Explorer"},
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Firefox", identity: "Firefox"},
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Safari", identity: "Safari"},
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Opera", identity: "Opera"}
        ]

    };
    
    BrowserDetect.init();
    document.write("você está usando <b>" + BrowserDetect.browser + "</b> na versão <b>" + BrowserDetect.version + "</b>");
```

### Exemplo de utilização

```js
var BrowserDetect = {
        init: function () {
            this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "Other";
            this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent) || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion) || "Unknown";
        },
        searchString: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var dataString = data[i].string;
                this.versionSearchString = data[i].subString;

                if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) !== -1) {
                    return data[i].identity;
                }
            }
        },
        searchVersion: function (dataString) {
            var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
            if (index === -1) {
                return;
            }

            var rv = dataString.indexOf("rv:");
            if (this.versionSearchString === "Trident" && rv !== -1) {
                return parseFloat(dataString.substring(rv + 3));
            } else {
                return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index + this.versionSearchString.length + 1));
            }
        },

        dataBrowser: [
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Chrome", identity: "Chrome"},
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "MSIE", identity: "Explorer"},
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Trident", identity: "Explorer"},
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Firefox", identity: "Firefox"},
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Safari", identity: "Safari"},
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Opera", identity: "Opera"}
        ]

    };
    BrowserDetect.init();


if (BrowserDetect.browser === "Chrome") {
 
  $("body").css('background','lightblue');
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
</body>
```

### [modernizr](http://tableless.com.br/utilizando-a-biblioteca-modernizr/)

Uma outra alternativa, seria utilizar o modernizr para determinar os recursos disponíveis no Browser do cliente, com modernizr você pode escrever estilos de forma arbitraria conforme a disponibilidade de recursos, olhe o exemplo

### modernizr Exemplo css

```
.loginBox {
    box-shadow:0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.no-boxshadow .loginBox {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #CCC;
}
```

Caso o recurso **box-shadow** não tenha suporte pelo navegador, style alternativo vai ser **.no-boxshadow .loginBox**

### [Yepnopejs](http://yepnopejs.com/)

Você pode combinar qualquer um dos recursos mencionados acima com Yepnopejs para carregar arquivos css ou js sobre alguma condição especial.

### Exemplo com modernizr

```
yepnope({
  test : Modernizr.fontface && Modernizr.canvas && Modernizr.cssgradients,
  yep  : 'normal.js',
  nope : ['polyfill.js', 'wrapper.js']
});
```

### Exemplo com a função js

```
 BrowserDetect.init();
  yepnope({
      test : BrowserDetect.browser == Chrome,
      yep  : 'normal.js',
      nope : ['polyfill.js', 'wrapper.js']
    });
```

Comment: Você respondeu como identificar, não como fazer o que ele pedia.

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback, isso se encontra no meio da resposta, 
"Veja esse exemplo com a função acima"
if (BrowserDetect.browser === "Chrome") {
 
  $("body").css('background','lightblue');
}
Não sei se foi você quem negativou, mas seria interessante comentar antes para evitar possíveis enganos, de qualquer forma obrigado pelo feedback.

Comment: acho que seria interessante demonstrar a maneira correta em cada método. Sim, eu fui quem deu o downvote =v... Vou reavaliar a resposta =)

Comment: Obrigado, estou reformulando a resposta, concordo com seu ponto de vista.

Comment: Lindo! Exatamente o que pensava e mais completo ainda...